# Как оформлять стилизованный текст (вывески, объявления, и т.д.)

Tags: общие-вопросы, литература, оформление-текста

Как оформлять такие вывески:

> Объявление на стене расплылось, словно его затянуло пленкой скользящей
> теплой воды; Экельс почувствовал, как веки, смыкаясь, на долю секунды
> прикрыли зрачки, но и в мгновенном мраке горели буквы:
>
> А/О САФАРИ ВО ВРЕМЕНИ
> ОРГАНИЗУЕМ САФАРИ В ЛЮБОЙ ГОД ПРОШЛОГО
> ВЫ ВЫБИРАЕТЕ ДОБЫЧУ
> МЫ ДОСТАВЛЯЕМ ВАС НА МЕСТО
> ВЫ УБИВАЕТЕ ЕЕ
>
> Рэй Брэдбери — "И грянул гром".

Или что-то типа (придумано на ходу):

> Надпись в газете гласила:
>
> ГОРЯЩИЕ ТУРЫ
> РАННЕЕ БРОНИРОВАНИЕ
> СИСТЕМА СКИДОК
>
> Самые низкие цены! Самый лучший сервис!

Интересует оформление этих элементов в художественном тексте (как в первом примере).

Нужны ли кавычки? Допускается ли использование прописных букв и отсутствие знаков препинания? Можете привести примеры оформления такого текста?

Comment: Вопросы оформительского искусства вообще на практике слегка касаются пунктуационных проблем, а дизайн вывесок предельно далёк и свободен от каких-либо правил письма. Примеров же разнообразного оформления баннеров множество на полях любого сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Силами этого редактора сделать что-то волюнтаристское нельзя, поэтому ввожу графический файл. Если исказил текст, то только из стремления к лаконичности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас, похоже, нет сформулированной проблемы. Предположу, что она может быть выражена значительно позже сбора базы, и материал для неё стоит искать в хорошо иллюстрированных изданиях, заточенных на его эмоциональности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ого! Большое спасибо за труд, но все же, есть ли какое-то устоявшееся **правило** (или какое-то соглашение) относительно оформления такого текста, как **части художественного произведения**?

Comment: Не понимаю до сих пор озабоченность якобы существованием правил. Вы, так кажется, жаждете каких-то ограничений. Так скажите прямо, в какой части они нужны, — формата произведения, его бюджета, адресности, возможностей в исполнительском звене...

Comment: Да, вы правы, хочется узнать об ограничениях. Ведь, наверняка, такие ситуации давно урегулированы пресловутыми *правилами*. 

На самом деле вопрос не совсем практический: просто собираю на компьютере небольшую библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы это оформляете на сайте, то на нём должны же быть какие-то стили, чтобы оформить примерно так:

Надпись в газете гласила:

```
ГОРЯЩИЕ ТУРЫ
РАННЕЕ БРОНИРОВАНИЕ
СИСТЕМА СКИДОК

Самые низкие цены! Самый лучший сервис!
```

Также можно написать «В газете говорилось о раннем бронировании билетов и системе скидок...», всё ограничивается вашей фантазией.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но: «*Интересует оформление этих элементов в художественном тексте (как в первом примере)*».